# How to use perl "require" function to call a perl script having a form and returning to original script when credentials are checked

Tags: perl

I'm working on a perl program where I have a script that displays some information. Before that page is displayed, I need to do some logins to the page. I have tried using "require" function in my main script that calls another script that asks for username and password. I need to return back to my original program automatically when login conditions are satisfied.
Please help me with it.

File 1:

```
require 'index.pl';
```

File 2:

```
sub print_form { 
    my $query = new CGI; use vars qw($userid $pword);
    my $password_dir = '/opt/app/d1pre2w1/sites/apache/cgi-bin-new/';
    my $pword_file = "commit_access_control.cfg";
    my $passwrd_location = $pword_file; 
    print("<td><form> \n", "USERNAME :", "<input type=text name=USERNAME >", "<br>", "PASSWORD :", "<input type=password name=PASSWORD>", "<br>", "<input type=submit name=login value=Login>", "</form>");
```

Answer (score 3):

From your question it looks like you have two problems:

1. You are using an ancient and ill-advised Perl tutorial.  Nobody in 2015 (much less 2001) would recommend using `require` for code reuse.
2. You do not understand how web applications work.  You can't write a single application script that will flow smoothly from state to state.  Instead, you must create a system that has a conversation with the client.  While CGI based techniques are hardly modern, they do work and form the basis for many current technologies.  Check out [Ovid's CGI Course](http://ovid-cgi-course.perl-begin.org/cgi-course/).  Once you are comfortable with that, check out [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious), [Catalyst](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst) or [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer) for more modern approaches to web development in Perl.

Comment: Ovid's tutorial is hilarious. How did you even find that? :)

Comment: @simbabque, by being old and remembering when it was a great new resource to throw to dot-com boom 1.0 newbs.